# Replace buttons: reference a Node in a context where it does not exist

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I'm trying to replace the first button with the second, and then with the 3rd. But after clicking the "button 1", the Developer Tools console return this:

```
Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it     does not exist.
           crearBoton2
```

¿Why crearBoton it dos not exist in that particular context?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div id="divi">
<button id="butti">Click Me</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And Js:

```
var getDi = document.getElementById("divi");
var getBu = document.getElementById("butti");
 //button 1
function crearBoton (){
    var crearBun = document.createElement("button");
crearBun.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Next"));
crearBun.setAttribute('id', 'boton');

getDi.replaceChild(crearBun, getBu);
crearBun.addEventListener('click', crearBoton2);

};

//button 2

function crearBoton2 (){
    var getCrearBotonId = document.getElementById("boton");
    var crearBud = document.createElement("button");
crearBud.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Next 2"));

    getDi.replaceChild(getCrearBotonId, crearBoton);
};

getBu.addEventListener('click', crearBoton);
```

Thank you!

Comment: `crearBoton` is never initialized

Comment: `crearBoton` is never initialized. `getCrearBotonId` returns a node, not an id so better change the name. What is `crearBoton` supposed to be? Is this the first button you created? If yes, then you are replacing the same node with itself. Maybe you meant to say `getDi.replaceChild(crearBud, getCrearBotonId)`

Comment: carmina, you re actually right! Ty!